# Display values from a table as column headers

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a list of employee names in a one column table. I would like the values from the table to display dynamically as column headings on a single row in a different table (dynamicly because the table will change, so a one-time transpose won't work).

Comment: You can use the TRANSPOSE function.  See this link: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/transpose.php

Comment: Tried that and get "multi-cell array formulas are not allowed in tables" As an FYI - both the source and destination are tables if that makes a difference.

Comment: And if I complete the function with ctrl+enter, I don't get an error message but instead get numbers "0 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 010 011 012 013 014 015 016 017 018 019 020 021 022 023 024 025
and when I revisit the cells the only value and no longer the transpose function.

Comment: I don't have access to Excel right now to diagnose what the problem might be.  However, there is another technique--copy and paste-special.  Paste-special has a transpose option.  Here is a link: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/transpose.html

Comment: Thank you. However paste special is a one shot deal. I need something that will update column headings automatically as employees are added or deleted from the other table.

Comment: In that case, TRANSPOSE wouldn't help, anyway, because that is also a one-time deal.  It would be worthwhile for you to edit your question to include this requirement.  It wasn't clear that that was what you meant by "dynamically".  I suspect you might need a VBA solution.

Comment: Tried index as well. I selected the range, and then 2 for the second item in the list [first being the column heading] and got a result of "0" and once again the formula was replaced with the value.

Comment: You could pre-populate an excess of column headings that link to cells in the source column, and hide them with an ISBLANK test until needed.

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes your list is in column A starting in row 2.  Your column headings will be in row 1 starting in column B.  Cell B1 would contain:

```
    =IF(COLUMN()>COUNTA($A:$A),"",INDIRECT("A"&COLUMN()))
```

If your layout is different, you would need to adjust.  Copy the formula across row 1 to more columns than you will need.  The heading will be blank until there is a value in the associated row of column A.